# Missing Required Module 'RxCocoaRuntime'

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, swift-package-manager, rx-cocoa

I am using RxCocoa in custom framework, so I am trying to inject dependencies with SPM and make that .xcframework.
I made the .xcframework, but the following error keeps appearing.

The process of creating and configuring the framework project and creating the xcframework was as follows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxO7B.png)

**Development Environment**

- CPU : Apple slicon (M1 PRO)
- MacOS : Ventura 13.1
- Xcode : 14.2(14C18)

**Step**

1. Create framework project (km-ios-sdk)
2. Set **Build Active Architecture Only** **YES** from **NO**
3. Mach-O Type is **Dynamic Library**
4. Write simple code using **RxSwift, RxCocoa**
5. Create .xcarchive and .xcframework

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme km-ios-sdk \
-archivePath ./archive/km-ios-sdk.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive \
-sdk iphoneos \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \

xcodebuild archive \
-scheme km-ios-sdk \
-archivePath ./archive/km-ios-sdk.framework-iphonesimulator-arm64.xcarchive \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework './archive/km-ios-sdk.framework-iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/km_ios_sdk.framework' \
-framework './archive/km-ios-sdk.framework-iphonesimulator-arm64.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/km_ios_sdk.framework' \
-output './KmSDK.xcframework'
```

6. Created Package.swift as below and uploaded it to git.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy7fk.png)
7. If you download and import km-ios-sdk as spm in the sample app, the error appears
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL5er.png)

It is the same even if you manually download .xcframework, and it is the same even if you download it with cocoapod. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We probably don't have the same dependency management configuration, but the following suggestions might help with the mysterious "Missing Required Module 'RxCocoaRuntime'" error that appears under some conditions.

- Try removing any missing libraries or frameworks shown in red in Xcode. They can happen when using static libraries in CocoaPods. For Swift, we should add "use_frameworks!"
- Check that all installed frameworks listed in the General tab exist by locating them in Finder.
- Try building the target for "Any iOS Device" if they do not exist.
- Finally, have a single source for RxSwift: SPM, Pods, or XCFrameworks. For example, RxDataSources, via SPM, incorporates RxSwift and RxCocoa. Therefore, a single package can cover multiple dependencies.